# Can't access SFTP with SELinux enabled

Tags: centos, sftp, selinux

I've setup SFTP on CentOS 6.8.

I've enabled SELinux, but I can't login using SFTP. I get a permission denied message.
I did `setsebool -P ssh_chroot_rw_homedirs on` but didn't work and I'm still getting the error.

It only logins the user when I disable SELinux.

Any idea what else I need to do to configure SELinux?

Comment: What are the AVCs that you can find in the audit log? What you mean by "enabled"? Was it disabled or only in permissive? Do you have correct SELinux labels?

Comment: That is a good thing to do. I believe they also told you to relabel all filesystem and how to do that.

Comment: See `man ftpd_selinux` https://linux.die.net/man/8/ftpd_selinux

Comment: here is the avc i found in the audit log

type=AVC msg=audit(1494231795.669:98456): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=8539 comm="sshd" path="/sftp/chroot" dev=dm-0 ino=5505029 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:chroot_user_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 tclass=dir